# How to print rows above and below certain value in column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a categorical variable assigned numerically in column as "777". What I want to do is when 777 is identified in a column, print 3 rows above and below that row. Below I am able to print 1 row above and below, how do I do 3, or any other number of rows above and below?

```
m = df['ResetPoint'] == 777
df = df[m.shift(-1)|m.shift()|m]
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple values of the reset value, one approach would be to find indices of 777 rows then form a temporary column using `.loc` to mark the rows to keep and then slice the DF using this. See simplified example below. The limits used in `.loc` could be changed as required. I assume you want to keep the 777 columns otherwise the code could be simply modified.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [x for x in range(20)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ResetPoint': data, 'y': data})

#set two arbitrary reset points
df.loc[5, 'ResetPoint'] = 777
df.loc[13, 'ResetPoint'] = 777
                  
m = (df[df['ResetPoint'] == 777]).index

#create temp column and set to 1 for rows to keep, else 0
df['temp'] = 0
for idx in m:
    df.loc[idx-3:idx+3, 'temp'] = 1
    
df = df[df['temp']>0].drop('temp', axis = 1)
print(df)
```

gives:

```
    ResetPoint   y
2            2   2
3            3   3
4            4   4
5          777   5
6            6   6
7            7   7
8            8   8
10          10  10
11          11  11
12          12  12
13         777  13
14          14  14
15          15  15
16          16  16
```

Comment: i only see that print once, but i have multiple rows that has the value 777. How do I get it so every time it encounters a 777, it prints 3 rows above and 3 rows below?

Comment: See edited code modified to meet the clarified requirement

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, the output looks great, exactly what I need. However, what is the "q" in reference to here? df = df[df['q']>0].drop('temp', axis = 1)

Comment: oops! The 'q' should be 'temp'. I used 'q' when testing code but did not change all the names before submitting answer. I'll edit it now.

Comment: You don't need to add and drop a new column, you can just use a separate Series: `temp = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)`. Then `temp.loc[idx-3:idx+3] = 1` and `df[temp==1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can basically just write a loop using what you have.

I'm assuming `n` (the number of rows of context) is never very large, so performance is a non-issue.

```
mask = m.copy()
n = 3
for i in range(1, n+1):
    mask |= m.shift(-i)  # above
    mask |= m.shift(i)  # below
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ResetPoint': list(range(10))})
df.loc[4, 'ResetPoint'] = 777
df
```

```
   ResetPoint
0           0
1           1
2           2
3           3
4         777
5           5
6           6
7           7
8           8
9           9
```

...

```
df[mask]
```

```
   ResetPoint
1           1
2           2
3           3
4         777
5           5
6           6
7           7
```